# TomEE 1.5.2 @Path annotation at interface level still not working

Tags: ejb, cxf, jax-rs, openejb, apache-tomee

Despite what is claimed [here](http://rmannibucau.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/tomeeopenejb-jaxrs-refactoring/):

> for applications not working because of missing @Path at class level
>   -> it should work now

I still have to annotate my endpoint implementations, as annotations on interfaces are not being picked up.

Is it related to the way I configure JAX-RS, or is it a bug still present in TomEE?

interface:

```
 @Path("myPath") public interface MyEndpoint { 

    @Path("{id}") String getById(@PathParam("id") long id);

 }
```

implementation:

```
 @Stateless class EJBBackedMyEndpoint implements MyEndpoint {

    String getById(long id) { return "foo"; }
 }
```

openejb-jar.xml

```
  <openejb-jar xmlns="http://www.openejb.org/openejb-jar/1.1">
    <ejb-deployment ejb-name="EJBBackedMyEndpoint">
        <properties>cxf.jaxrs.providers = exceptionMapper</properties>
    </ejb-deployment>
  </openejb-jar>
```

resources.xml

```
<resources> 
  <Service id="exceptionMapper" class-name="package.MyExceptionMapper"/>
</resources>
```

beans.xml present with just empty root element

**Update:**

- JAX-RS Spec apparently doesn't mention class-level annotations at all
- @Consumes and @Produces work when applied on the interface,
- @Path (class level) doesn't work when applied on the interface,
- @Path on method level is honoured when routing requests,  however the UriBuilder is failing:
  `UriBuilder.path(EJBBackedMyEndpoint.class, "getById")` throws `IllegalArgumentException: No Path annotation for 'retrieve' method`.

Answer (score 2):

That blog post is perhaps misleading.  Putting `@Path`, `@GET`, `@PathParam` or other JAX-RS annotations on an interface is not supported by JAX-RS.  Per spec all these need to be on the "Resource Class", which is the `@Stateless` bean class in this situation.

If you move `@Path` from the interface to bean class it should work.  At least it should get further.

Comment: I remember this worked for me when I was using plain CXF. 
Could you point me to the relevant part of the spec?

Comment: Looks like I'm wrong in at least part of that answer.  Section "3.6 Annotation Inheritance" of JAX-RS 1.1 says you definitely can put annotations on method of an interface.  It only mentions methods and the spec example still has the `@Path` annotation on the bean class.  I grepped through the TCK (compatibility test suite) and there are tests that have interfaces with annotated methods, but no tests with the interface using annotations outside of methods.  We pass the TCK for JAXRS so this should work.  But it doesn't seem annotations on non-methods of an interface is covered in spec or TCK.

Comment: After a careful reading I think that section 3.6 doesn't mention class level annotations at all. 
Still I think CXF allows this, so maybe I was just sloppy and left out some other annotation on the class.

Comment: Try adding the class-level `@Path` annotation to the `EJBBackedMyEndpoint` class, leaving the other method-level annotations in the interface.  Fingers crossed that should "just work" (famous last words).  It seems to be tested in the TCK, so it should be covered.

Comment: Actually the method level annotations work fine on the interface (including @Path). It's only the class-level @Path annotation that is not applied

Comment: See update to my question, this behaviour is getting rather inconsistent.